# How to know the textView content height by loading html string data?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, textview

I have html string data, and I show it in a textview.
But I want to know the textView content height about my html data.
Because I want to add the textview as a subview of a UIScrollView to show the data.
I also want the textview not scroll, and show all the data to user.
So, I need to know the height of textview.
Have any idea to me?
Thanks.

```
do {
    let attrStr = try NSAttributedString(
        data: htmlString.data(using: String.Encoding.unicode, allowLossyConversion: true)!,
        options: [ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil)
        self.textView.attributedText = attrStr //how to know the height about the content?
} catch let error {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: if you set textView.isScrollEnabled = false, and do not limit it's height, it willll automaticallly resize to fit the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this function to get the height of label and then pass that height to textView. Hope this will resolve your problem.

```
func heightForHtmlString(_ text: NSMutableAttributedString, font:UIFont) -> CGFloat {
  let label:UILabel = UILabel.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
  label.numberOfLines = 0
  label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
  label.font = font
  label.attributedText = text as NSAttributedString
  label.sizeToFit()
  return label.frame.height 
}
```